# How to refer Certification file during SpringBoot startup

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, resources, launch

I've a Mavenized project (web application) and I use SpringBoot to package and run it. I package it as a war and then launch it using `spring-boot:run` maven goal.
The application calls few 3rd party vendor RESTful APIs that requires certificates.
I've the `cacert` file from vendor; for my localhost, I've kept the cert file on my filesystem and referring it using `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` command line argument during SpringBoot launch [So, something like: `javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to cacert file on my file system>`]
I've now decided to keep the cacert file in my classpath(so in some folder under src/main/resources).
I want SpringBoot to load this resource at the startup and refer it using `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property.
Can someone pls assist on how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of ssl property ( add these to application.properties file) :

```
server.ssl.ciphers= # Supported SSL ciphers.
server.ssl.client-auth= # Whether client authentication is wanted ("want") or needed ("need"). Requires a trust store.
server.ssl.enabled= # Enable SSL support.
server.ssl.enabled-protocols= # Enabled SSL protocols.
server.ssl.key-alias= # Alias that identifies the key in the key store.
server.ssl.key-password= # Password used to access the key in the key store.
server.ssl.key-store= # Path to the key store that holds the SSL certificate (typically a jks file).
server.ssl.key-store-password= # Password used to access the key store.
server.ssl.key-store-provider= # Provider for the key store.
server.ssl.key-store-type= # Type of the key store.
server.ssl.protocol=TLS # SSL protocol to use.
server.ssl.trust-store= # Trust store that holds SSL certificates.
server.ssl.trust-store-password= # Password used to access the trust store.
server.ssl.trust-store-provider= # Provider for the trust store.
server.ssl.trust-store-type= # Type of the trust store.
```

Hope it help, reference : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html